# How to find the type of Nvidia GPU (either Tesla, Fermi or Kepler) by the program

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Can anyone tell me how to find the GPU type (Fermi, Tesla or Kepler) by the program, so that the would call the correct function depending on the GPU type.

Through **cudaDeviceProp.major**, I was able to differentiate Fermi and Tesla through their compute capability. But I am not able to differentiate between Fermi and Kepler.

Do anyone know how to find it.

Comment: You should be able to - Telsa cards are `major=1`, Fermi cards are `major=2` and Kepler cards are `major=3`.

Comment: No, the major number of Kepler cards are not 3. For kepler, the major number is 2

Comment: You are wrong. It is 3. See Appendix F.5 of the CUDA 4.2 programming guide.

Comment: Or, from section 2.5 of that same guide: "The 
major revision number is 3 for devices based on the Kepler architecture, 2 for devices based on the Fermi architecture, and 1 for devices based on the Tesla architecture."

Comment: So Tesla is both the name of the first architecture and the name of the professional compute cards for all the architectures. Confusing.

Comment: @RogerDahl: I think that "Tesla" moniker for the G80/90/G200 architectures were somewhat retrospectively applied. Certainly I don't remember "Tesla" being applied to the *architecture* at the times the first couple of generations of hardware appeared.

Comment: I thought it was widely known that "Tesla" was the code-name for the first generation of CUDA-capable GPUs (i.e. SM 1.x).  And yes, Tesla also refers to passively-cooled GPUs intended for use in data centers. Roger is correct, it is confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question, `cudaDeviceProp.major=3` identifies current Kepler cards, `cudaDeviceProp.major=2` is for Fermi and `cudaDeviceProp.major=1` for G8x/G9x/G2xx cards, as illustrated by this SDK deviceQuery output:

```
/deviceQuery Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Found 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 680"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version 4.2 / 4.2
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number: 3.0
Total amount of global memory: 2048 MBytes (2147287040 bytes)
( 8) Multiprocessors x (192) CUDA Cores/MP: 1536 CUDA Cores
GPU Clock rate: 706 MHz (0.71 GHz)
Memory Clock rate: 3004 Mhz
```

Comment: Where is deviceQuery ? does it inside nvidia cuda Samples?